# Не хватает метки "запрос-слова"?

Tags: предложение, статус-отклонено, метки

Не хватает метки «запрос-слова»?

См.вопрос [Как сказать одним словом «человек, который подделывает документы»?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431633/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BA-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B)

Answer (score 2):

По достижении 150 баллов репутации любой участник может создавать свои метки. Подробнее — в [Справке](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

---

На мой взгляд, необходимости в данной метке нет, потому что количество вопросов, в которых она может использоваться, мало.